# UITabBarController UISplitViewController hidesBottomBarWhenPushed

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on a universal app. Below is my setup

I have a UISplitViewContoller as the third tab of a UITabBarController. 
The SplitViewController is having 2 UINavigationViewController both leading to 2 different UIViewControllers lets say (A & B)

[image: Storyboard]
(hope image makes sense)

In iPad the app works fine both A and B are visible. In iPhone only A is visible, when I select's an item in the A then it navigates to B
What I want is to hide the bottom bar when B is pushed.

I have given `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` (in very possible view controllers)

In other UIViewControllers above code works fine, since there is no UISplitViewController

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Nope had to find some other alternative

Comment: @vinbhai4u could you explain the alternative that you took? Would be awesome :)